# Merge statement in insert trigger wiping out Identity value?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014

I am issuing a sql statement that is

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (.....;  
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

`Table1` has an identity column. This worked great and in C# I would be getting back the newly assigned identity value.

Then I added an insert, update trigger that has a single `MERGE` statement in it that either inserts or updates a record in another table. That other table does not have any identity in it. The insert part of the merge is firing in the trigger when I am adding new rows to `Table1`.

Now, the first SQL statement returns null and I can't get the identity value for `Table1`. I tried

```
SELECT @@Identity
```

and even

```
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('Table1')
```

but they all return null. If I comment out the merge in the trigger, I start getting back the identity value.

How do I get my identity value or get the merge to stop clearing it out?

Comment: That is odd as SCOPE_IDENTITY() should be returning Table1 identity as I read the documentation.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx

Comment: Try OUTPUT INSERTED.ID  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx